# Preseeding.cfg can support OEM-Install?

Tags: system-installation, oem

I create preseeding.cfg and following below step. May I know the Ubuntu OEM-Install can auto installation?

1. Download boot.img.gz and decompress that.
2. Copy syslinux folder in USB stick
3. Creating preseeding.cfg and put in syslinux folder
4. Modifying below script in grub.cfg
   menuentry "OEM install (for manufacturers)" {
   set gfxpayload=keep
   linux   /syslinux/vmlinuz file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed preseed/file=/hd-media/preseed.cfg auto=true boot=casper only-ubiquity quiet splash oem-config/enable=true ---
   initrd  /syslinux/initrd
   }